# SMD crystal identification

Tags: stm32, surface-mount, crystal

I think it looks like a fork of an oscillator and also connected to the PC14-OSC32_IN and PC15-OSC32_OUT pins of the STM32 F072C8. But the markings "A801N" are not particularly well indexed by google, as it seems. I'm not that much interested in the exact model, more in the frequency of this crystal. My best guess is 8 MHz, but I would like to be a bit more certain than that.

[image: crystal with "A801N" markings]

Comment: The LSE works up to 1 MHz external clock, and likely won't support crystals other than 32768 Hz tuning fork watch crystals. If that is an 8 MHz crystal like you guess, then it won't work anyway. It likely is not a 8 MHz crystal, unless someone designed in or mounted a wrong crystal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a **32.768 kHz crystal resonator** for the STM32F072C8's internal RTC (real-time clock). It is very likely the mentioned type below. However it could also be a clone of it.

Manufacturer: Seiko Epson Corporation

Manufacturer series: FC-135 or FC-135R

Manufacturer product page:

https://www5.epsondevice.com/en/products/crystal_unit/fc135.html
https://www5.epsondevice.com/en/products/crystal_unit/fc135r.html

Manufacturer data sheet:

https://support.epson.biz/td/api/doc_check.php?dl=app_FC-135&lang=en
https://support.epson.biz/td/api/doc_check.php?dl=app_FC-135R&lang=en

The meaning of the marking can be seen in the following picture

[image: Marking Description]

Answer (score 3):

According to the datasheet of the STM32F072C8. The OSC32_IN and OSC32_OUT pins are for the 32.768 kHz crystal that is used by the RTC. So it's a 32.768 kHz tuning fork crystal.

[image]

Edit: It's likely a FC-135 by YXC: https://www.yangxing.hk/products-detail/fc-135